# Controller does not recognize correct handler method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller with methods as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/**")
public class EmployeeInfoController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEmployeeInfoCriteria(@ModelAttribute("employeeInfoParam") EmployeeInfoParam employeeInfoParam) {
            .....
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/details/{empId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEmployeeDetailsById(@PathVariable String empId) {
            ......
    }
}
```

I expected whenever I `/application/employee/`, it would show search page and it does. But it doesn't show employee details page, when I submit request `/application/emp/details/101`, it goes search page instead of details page.
The log shows below:

```
09:45:20,937 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG [RequestMappingHandlerMapping:229] - Looking up handler method for path /employee/details/400000000022161
09:45:20,938 INFO  [STDOUT] TRACE [RequestMappingHandlerMapping:267] - Found 2 matching mapping(s) for [/employee/details/400000000022161] : [{[/employee/**],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}, {[/employee/**/details/{empId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
09:45:20,939 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG [RequestMappingHandlerMapping:234] - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.application.web.controller.EmployeeInfoController.getEmployeeInfoCriteria(com.application.web.form.EmployeeInfoParam)]
```

My understanding was, If I don't mention any sub-urls in place of ** (which is in the class level), it would take `getEmployeeInfoCriteria` i.e. `/application/employee/`.
If I mention a sub-url, like `/application/employee/details/1001`, it would be handled by `getEmployeeDetailsById`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to use ** in class level request mapping, just use

`@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/")`

Answer (score 2):

The wildcard is stopping it from resolving the next URL. Get rid of it.